# Get text separated by tags / BS4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

How could I get text from tag, where attributes are separated by 
 or  tags? For example for 'Adresa:' in the code below, I tried to get an address: `soup.find('strong', text = 'Adresa:')` but I don't know how to get the text after `<strong>Adresa:</strong>` and before `<strong>Telefón:</strong>`.

The output should be: `Adresa: Obecný úrad Nána, Madáchova 32, 943 60 Nána`

Here is the example of the code:

```
<p>
<strong>Adresa:</strong>Obecný úrad Nána<br></br>Madáchova 32<br></br>943 60 Nána<br></br><br></br><strong>Telefón:</strong>036/759 70 06<br></br><strong>Fax:</strong>036/7597 007<br></br><strong>Web:</strong><a href="http://www.obecnana.sk"></a><br></br>
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to find the `strong` tag by text, then using [`find_next_siblings()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling), find all sibling tags and stop on the next `strong` tag:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

data = u"""
<p>
<strong>Adresa:</strong>Obecný úrad Nána<br></br>Madáchova 32<br></br>943 60 Nána<br></br><br></br>
<strong>Telefón:</strong>036/759 70 06<br></br>
<strong>Fax:</strong>036/7597 007<br></br>
<strong>Web:</strong><a href="http://www.obecnana.sk"></a><br></br>
</p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

address = soup.find(text='Adresa:')
texts = []
for item in address.parent.find_next_siblings():
    if item.name == 'strong':
        break
    text_before = item.previous_sibling
    if isinstance(text_before, NavigableString):
        texts.append(text_before)

print ' '.join(texts)
```

It prints:

```
Obecný úrad Nána Madáchova 32 943 60 Nána
```

---

Then, you can extract the code into a nice reusable function:

```
def get_section_text(text):
    section = soup.find(text=text)
    if not section:
        raise ValueError("Section not found")

    texts = []
    for item in section.parent.find_next_siblings():
        if item.name == 'strong':
            break
        text_before = item.previous_sibling
        if isinstance(text_before, NavigableString):
            texts.append(text_before)

    return ' '.join(texts)
```

And call it for different sections:

```
print get_section_text('Adresa:')
print get_section_text('Telefón:')
print get_section_text('Fax:')
```

It would print:

```
Obecný úrad Nána Madáchova 32 943 60 Nána
036/759 70 06
036/7597 007
```

For a non-existing section:

```
print get_section_text('ILLEGAL SECTION')
```

it raises an exception

```
ValueError: Section not found
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next_sibling` to iterate over the siblings of the `<strong>Adresa:</strong>` tag until the next `<strong>` tag is seen, accumulating strings as you go. Finally `join()` the strings together using `', '` as the separator:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<p>
<strong>Adresa:</strong>Obecný úrad Nána<br></br>Madáchova 32<br></br>943 60 Nána<br></br><br></br><strong>Telefón:</strong>036/759 70 06<br></br><strong>Fax:</strong>036/7597 007<br></br><strong>Web:</strong><a href="http://www.obecnana.sk"></a><br></br>
</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

e = soup.find('strong', text = 'Adresa:')
e = e.next_sibling
strings = []
while e and e.name != 'strong':
    if e.string is not None:
        strings.append(e)
    e = e.next_sibling

>>> print 'Adresa: %s' % ', '.join(strings)
Adresa: Obecný úrad Nána, Madáchova 32, 943 60 Nána
```

Comment: I think you are basically reinventing `find_next_siblings()` here.

Comment: I suppose so, but this seems more concise to me for this particular application.